# Setting UIImage to fit iPhone5 and iPhone6

Tags: ios, objective-c

We would like to set in code, an image to fit both iPhone5 and iPhone6.

We have an image, that its size is ready for `iPhone6` , and we would like it to be scaled and placed on the same position on `iPhone5` .

So ,the next code,is working good on `iPhone6` , but on the iPhone5 the image is not scaled, i guess because i take the size of the *actual image*, and not the ratio to the screen size :
(i also have launch images on the app)

```
 UIImage *imgt=[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"];
    UIImageView *title=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((width-imgt.size.width)/2.0,imgt.size.height/2.0, imgt.size.width, imgt.size.height)];
    title.image=imgt;
    [self.view addSubview:title];
```

Question is, how can i get the **scaled image size** *on the iPhone5s* ? what he does is to take the actual size(the big one of iPhone6) , but because i know that the image size is scaled, **i was expecting to get the scaled size with**  `imgt.size.width`

Comment: Have you looked into the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView`? If you're simply doing a full-screen `UIImage`, it might be a simple case of setting the `UIImageView.contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a separate image that is scaled to the iPhone 5/5s. You could do this in Photoshop or some other editing program. After making the scaled image you could set up a conditional statement to check if the device the user is using. I'm assuming you know how to do this, but I'll put some code down below anyways.

**To Check Which Device A User is Using**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString *) platform {
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *device = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", device, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
free(device);
return platform;
}
```

This would make a NSString that could be used to determine the device. You could then set up an if then statement with it. You could check the platform string against another device string.

Comment: If he's concerned about the size of his app bundle (especially if he has a lot of images where this might be true), it would probably be better for him to include a large, stock image and then use a category on `UIImage` to dynamically resize/crop the image at runtime. Apple's tools for this are pretty good and pretty fast. That could easily saved tens of megabytes of space in some cases. Also, I think it's much easier to determine device by inspecting screen size. Here's how I do it...

Comment: Here's an example of what I do (the others are very similar to this): `#define IS_IPHONE_4     (MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) == 480.0)`

Comment: thanks, but you cant put that condition every time you want to load image, its a lot of code ... i have to seek for another solution.